# The Migration failed because index name already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to migrate a new model but when I run rake db:migrate it aborts with this error message: Index name 'index_section_edits_on_admin_user_id' on table 'section_edits' already exists

I tried deleting the index but I still get the same error message. Any help would be appreciate!

Thanks

Comment: Show your migration and schema.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the index name in your migration.

```
add_index :users, :email, unique: true, name: 'my_index_name'
```